Getting "Undefined variable $slot" when trying to render blade component on Laravel with Livewire 3
Hello I made a new project to see why i'm having problems when rendering blade with livewire 3 components. I have my app.blade.php and my counter.blade.php with Counter livewire component.
The livewire config file has 'layout' => 'components.layouts.app' and followed the livewire documentation for the layouts but still having the error of Undefined variable $slot. Tried everything to solve it.
The app.blade.php is located in resources/views/components/layouts/app.blade.php
app.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>{{ $title ?? 'Page Title' }}</title>
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>

<body>
    @if ($slot->isEmpty())
        This is default content if the slot is empty.
    @else
        {{ $slot }}
    @endif
</body>

</html>

counter.blade.php
<x-layouts.app>
<div>
    <h1>{{ $count }}</h1>
 
    <button wire:click="increment">+</button>
    
    <button wire:click="decrement">-</button>
</div>
</x-layouts.app>

Counter livewire component
<?php
 
namespace App\Livewire;
 
use Livewire\Component;
 
class Counter extends Component
{
    public $count = 1;
 
    public function increment()
    {
        $this->count++;
    }
 
    public function decrement()
    {
        $this->count--;
    }
 
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.counter');
    }
}


Why are you using this
"@if ($slot->isEmpty())
This is default content if the slot is empty.
@else
{{ $slot }}
@endif"
instead of only
{{ $slot }}

The layout is wrapped onto your component by Livewire, you don't need to specify <x-layouts.app> and </x-layouts.app>. Your view must contain only the <div>......</div> HTML

How Blade Components Work with Slots

The $slot variable in Blade components refers to the content you pass between the component tags (<x-layouts.app>...</x-layouts.app>).
By default, Blade will handle empty or missing slot content without the need for a manual check like @if ($slot->isEmpty()).
If no content is provided for the slot, it simply remains empty, so you can directly render {{ $slot }}.

In your app.blade.php layout, you can remove the conditional check and directly use:
<body>
   {{ $slot }}
</body>

If you want to display default content when no content is passed to the slot, you can handle it like this:
<body>
   {{ $slot ?? 'This is default content if the slot is empty.' }}
</body>

